# phpStorm 7 how to fix NodeJS/Javascript unresolved function from object

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have the following NodeJS module

```
/**
 * @param {string} a 
 * @param {string} b
 * @return {Object}
 */
module.exports = function(a, b) {
  return {
    foo: function(a, b, c) {}
  };
}
```

I then load the module and try to use the results

```
var Factory = require("./my-module.js");
var configuredObject = Factory(1, 2);

configuredObject.foo(1, 2, 3);  <-- Unresolved function or method foo()
```

I had a look at some other suggestions on SO and [related](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5366907) [links](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504337#5504337) however the suggestion of replicating the outline of the Object so that I could then use JSDoc seems very dirty as I would have to manually copy/paste the outline into every user of the module, which is tedious, and of course very error prone eg:

```
var MyModuleOutline = {
  foo: function(a, b, c) {} 
}

/** @type {MyModuleOutline} */
var configuredObject = Factory(1, 2);
```

I'm using phpStorm 7.1, and I'm hoping that there's been improvements with code completion/understanding that I just don't know about yet.

What else can I do to remove the "Unresolved function" message?

Comment: I suggest you to open an issue in their issue tracker youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: @Maks3w If there is no existing solution, the I will open a ticket.

Comment: Those guys answer very quickly so try it anyway

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ways to document properties of the returned object are described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsdoc-users/TMvUedK9tC4) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/issues/detail?id=265). But none of them will actually work in WebStorm. And properties resolving should work in your case without JSDoc. Logged as [WEB-11755](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11755)

Comment: You'll need to mark the issue that I created in YouTrack as a duplicate then (I don't have permission to apparently).